# Which one is more secure for user authenticaion, AJAX or HTML (form submission) and how?

Tags: html, ajax, authentication, iframe, form-submit

Don't know why people do not practice AJAX implementation for authentication systems. Is it insecure? If yes how? I have developed an authentication system that submit user information through an iframe, but the problem is it opens a new window in IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't know why people do not practice AJAX implementation for authentication systems.

Usually because the differences between "logged in" and "not logged in" are quite significant, so the cost of reloading the entire page is relatively insignificant.

> Is it insecure?

Not intrinsically. Security comes from SSL, not from forms or JavaScript.

Comment: For the first point: What's wrong with redirection after successful login? Anyway, thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @Saiful — It is significantly more complicated and doesn't have any significant benefits.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, they are both sent exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It's all just http.

It makes a difference if you are sending authentication over ssl, how cookies or authentication headers are encrypted and so on.

What doesn't makes a difference is if it's an AJAX request or an IFrame or a Form post and so on.